Cannot install working grub on LFS Linux
I have been trying to install grub for my LSF Linux but I feel a bit lost. That is because every time I install it (no errors shown) it doesn't boot my os but grub rescue shell. I tried searching for etc/default/grub file but could not find it. I need it to change os-probe mode to true so while configuring grub it detects OS. Can anyone help me?
I tried changing some settings in files so far to no avail.

No word given as to what your setup is, whether it's BIOS or EFI, what your partitions are, nothing.
